# How do you create a closed funnel?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

how is it possible to create closed funnel? Ie I would like to see how many users made some action and then uninstalled app.
ie. event_lost_game -> uninstall. Currently funnels are open so it doesn't tell you how many user's made step 1 and then step 2. It only shows how many users made both steps separately.

I found it in [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#analytics-closed-funnel) but it's not clear what you need to do.

It looks like one need to create open funnel and audience based on all events in funnel and then filter funnel based on it.
Anyone who has experience with it? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do want this funnel to measure? Users who have *ever* logged event_lost_game who also uninstalled?  If so, create an audience of users who log "event_lost_game" and apply it to the app_remove event report.

Comment: @SteveGanem I want to measure ie how many user's made some action and then proceed to another action. also I want to see conversion after every step.
ie. play_level_2 (100users) -> level_win (50users 50%) -> buy_in_app_product (1user 1%).
Basically I want to see in at which step in flow we are losing most users.
If I use current open funnels, it just show total count of every event and it doesn't matter if user made previous step. How can I do ie example above? Thanks

Comment: As you said, funnels are currently open, so the completion of step one is not required for the inclusion in step two.  There is no way to produce the report you are trying to produce.

Comment: What's the purpose of having open funnels at all? Then we can as well just look at one graph at a time. Closed funnels seem to be what everyone would want, to actually being able to follow a user and see where they drop out.

Comment: As I understand what the FAQ says is to have multiple variants of same event (sounds cumbersome and ridiculous, adds so much of extra code) so that you can have closed funnel. So, any event (say event-2) will have only one entry that is from previous event (event_1).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an audience with a filter by `event_lost_game`.
2. Create a funnel with `event_lost_game` -> `uninstall` event sequence.
3. Filter this funnel by created audience.

Answer (score 1):

One option that might be helpful is to set a user property for "level=x" and then log events for play_level, level_win and buy_in_app_product.  Then, create a funnel that includes these three events and filter that report by User Property level=x.

Comment: isn't it possible if I create funnel and audience with all 3 events and then I filter funnel with this audience?

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue you can create closed funnels by having your firebase-analytics synced into BigQuery. 
In BigQuery you can do a closed funnel, I do this quite often because I need to get the users you did go through the full funnel to target them or other how to understand who they are. 
Someone wrote about it here also: https://medium.com/@kerp/how-do-i-create-a-closed-funnel-in-google-analytics-for-firebase-using-bigquery-6eb2645917e1