# Testing Firebase Funnels

Tags: uninstallation, firebase-analytics

I wanted to know a simple question regarding setting up my first funnel in Firebase. If we wanted to know which unique users (on a specific day) first opened the app and removed it, would the below simple funnel be sufficient ? Note: On the filter date, I selected "Yesterday".

**Question:**

*Would this selection enable me then to view only those users that did "First Open" (my base) AND "App removal" on the **same day** (on D0) ? or is this an open funnel of a wider base: i.e. users that somewhere in the past did first_open and did a app_remove yesterday ?*

I read that Firebase is only considering open funnels by default, and if we want to make funnels more "closed", we would have to log separate custom properties and filter to form closed funnels (Source: [How do you create a closed funnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948649/how-do-you-create-a-closed-funnel)). So, there is a bit confusion of how open this funnel really is.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Firebase Analytics funnels are open; meaning that completion of the first step is not strictly a prerequisite of the second step.  In this case, your sequence of events is a strict sequence (i.e. you can't log an app_remove without first having logged a first_open), but still, the query for each step is independent for "Yesterday".  In other words, the funnel is effectively as you suspect : step 1 shows users who have logged first_open yesterday and step 2 shows users who have logged app_remove yesterday (regardless of when they first opened the app).

Your options are :

1. Use the "Last 7 days" date range instead of Yesterday and filter the funnel by the built-in "New users" user property.
2. Create an audience of users who log app_remove whose First Open Time user property = [some future day] and then after that day passes, use this audience as a filter on your funnel.
3. Perform this analysis in BigQuery instead.

Comment: Great, thanks ! I will set this up and post some feedback here in due time :)